# Using tinytest within a testing function

Tags: r, unit-testing

I use `tinytest` to test a package. As I am testing multiple similar inputs with the same expected results, I created a small test-helper-function within the `test_*.R` file.

However, if a test failed, I do not get the typical failed notification. For example, in the following function, I would expect to get a summary or a direct failure but instead it returns

```
library(tinytest)

test_function <- function() {
  expect_equal(1, 1)
  expect_equal(2, 1)
  expect_equal(1, 1)
}

test_function()
#> ----- PASSED      : <-->
#>  call| test_function()
```

Note that if I replace `tinytest` with `testthat` the function stops and returns an error as expected.

Is this expected behavior or what did I miss when reading the documentation and how can I use tinytest within such a testing function?

Answer (score 1):

So what I was able to gather is that your test_function() is returning the result of the last expect_equal() inside the function. Which means if you change the last expect_equal(1, 1) to expect_equal(2, 1) or any other false result, the test_function will return FAILED results.

Now if you want to fetch the results of each expect_eqaul() inside your function, you can try this:

```
library(tinytest)
test_function <- function(){
    Results <- c(expect_equal(1, 1),expect_equal(2, 1),expect_equal(1, 1))
    return(Results)
}
test_function()
```

This will give you a list of Boolean Values as a result.

```
> test_function()
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

or to test if all tests where positive:

```
> expect_true(all(test_function()))
----- FAILED[data]: <-->
call| expect_true(all(test_function()))
diff| Expected TRUE, got FALSE
```

Comment: This is a good workaround (haven't actually thought about returning the result values), but unfortunately this does not inform me on which test has failed (compared to `testthat`). Thanks for your answer nonetheless!